# Carbon serialize error in SerializableClosure

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-9

- Laravel Version: 9.15.0
- PHP Version: 8.1.6

#### Description:

I get an error when I use Carbon inside Serializable Closure. However, there is no error when I use \DateTime.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

**Error "DateTime::getTimezone(): The DateTime object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor" with using Carbon:**

```
$carbon = new Carbon('-1 day');

dispatch(static function () use ($carbon) {
    \Log::debug('DATE: ' . $carbon->format('c'));
});
```

**Success case with \DateTime:**

```
$carbon = new \DateTime('-1 day');

dispatch(static function () use ($carbon) {
    \Log::debug('DATE: ' . $carbon->format('c'));
});
```

Also I catch error **The DateTime object has not been correctly initialized by its constructor in ........../vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php:638** bug in case:

```
class Product {
              private $updateDate ?Carbon;

              public function __construct(?Carbon $updateDate){
                           $this->updateDate = $updateDate;
              }
}

/** @var Product[] $products */
$products = [
     new Product(now()),
];

dispatch(static function () use ($products) {
         //business logic
});
```

Comment: I found method with error. It is `\Laravel\SerializableClosure\Serializers\Native::mapByReference`

`$reflection = new ReflectionObject($data);`
`$reflection->getProperties()` don't return `date` and `timezone` properties of parent \DateTime, and after set values to all props its keep undefined.

Comment: Because `date` and `timezone` are in the property $dumpProperties of `Carbon\Traits\Serialization` trait.

Comment: I managed to fix it this way
``` 
           if ($data instanceof UnitEnum) {
                $this->scope[$instance] = $data;

                return;
            }

            if ($data instanceof \DateTime){
                $this->scope[$instance] = $data;

                return;
            }

            $reflection = new ReflectionObject($data);
```